# Doing call to prisma client from load function in Svelte Kit

Tags: typescript, svelte, prisma, sveltekit

I'm using Prisma.io to write a database and would like to call the Prisma client from a typescript function.

I tried  to use the load function of Svelte kit and  also writing the call in a hidden _api.ts file but it didn't work. The Prisma client is complaining that it cannot be run from the browser. I understand it should somehow be run only on the server. What is the proper way to use Prisma with Svelte kit and run calls on the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "load" function in Svelte may run on the server or in the browser, so this is probably the cause of the error.

I suggest you turn the _api.ts into a callable endpoint. You then need to make sure that the api.ts exports a function named 'get' (or other methd). More info here: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#routing-endpoints

Once this is done, you should be able to browse to the api route directly, and you should see the outcome of your 'get' function in the api.ts file.

Then, in your "load" function, you can use the 'fetch' method to access that route and grab the data. In Svelte, the fetch method works on both the server and the browser. https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#loading-input-fetch

Update:

To do 'POST' endpoints, you need to export a function called 'post' in your endpoint file. I suggest you console.log the request to see what you data you receive when the endpoint is called:

```js
export async function get(request) {
  console.log(request);
  return {
    body: { success: true },
  };
}
```

Comment: Okay, so I will have to bascally convert the current REST api I have in django into a Prisma API in Svelte trhough endpoints. I got the get API endpoint working, but the post api endpoint not yet. How do i resuest the route parameters inside of a post function?

Comment: You'll need to export a function called 'post'  and /  or 'get' in your end point files. Its easiest if you console.log the request out to see what you receive when the function is called.

Comment: thank you. This helps, I could write a POST function. However, when replacing the rest fetch call by a prisma call inside the get api endpoint, the await block breaks and my code seems to be stuck on an await. I don't understand how prisma changed this. Should the return type of the get pi endpoint have a specific shape?

Comment: Have you wrapped your await with a try / catch? The docs show the structure of the return object. You can search on the docs for: '{ status, headers, body }'